# Manage multiple files upload in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, request, dropzone.js

I am trying to upload multiple files in Django and store them in the system through DropzoneJS. I get files in the MultiValueDict Dictionary in request.FILES. But, it looks like:

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'file[1]': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: DSC07077.jpg (image/jpeg)>], u'file[0]': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: DSC06856.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

The files uploaded are not in the same key, so I cannot use request.FILES.getlist('file') and I am not sure how should I get it.

My views function is:

```
def upload_files(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print request.FILES
    if request.FILES:
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            handle_uploaded_file(f)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/swupdate/index/')


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open( settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f.name, 'wa') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

My form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
file  = forms.FileField()
```

My Template form:

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action='/index/upload_files/' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<!-- Now setup your input fields -->
<input type="email" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />                                         
<div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->
<button id='SubmitAll' type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
</form>

<script src="{% static 'js/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

    // The configuration we've talked about above
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    addRemoveLinks: true,


    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click",      function(e) {
    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
    // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
    // Hide the success button or the complete form.
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
    // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
    // Redirect user or notify of success.
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
    // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
    // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
    });
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a small tutorial I followed to use dropzonejs in Django : [DropzoneJS & Django: How to build a file upload form](https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/dropzonejs-django-how-to-build-a-file-upload-form/)

Comment: I used that tutorial before but I don't know why, the options were ignored by Django and the files were uploaded immediately. I have mixed like all the tutorials in internet. I hope someone could help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the files are added to the dict in different keys but you can do something like:

```
for key in request.FILES:  # So each iteration, key will have the key of the dict
```

In your code you should try:

```
# Your code ......
for key in request.FILES:
    handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES[key])
return HttpResponseRedirect('/swupdate/index/')
# ... Your code ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Liarez, your solution works fine! :). I have tried something similar but I realize with your solution that I had a problem with privileges in the folder where I stored the files.

Comment: Damn file permissions... I've broke my head to fix issues like that! I'm happy to help !